# Non null-terminated string compiler option for gcc

Tags: c++, c, string, gcc, null-terminated

### Update

turns out this is just another case of "c++ is not c blues"

---

What I want

```
const char hex[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

the only thing that works

```
char hex[16] = "0123456789ABCDE"; hex[15] = "F";
```

are there any compiler options or something I can do to make strings not null terminated in the gcc compiler. so that I can make a(n) constant array

Comment: Another example of why you shouldn't generally tag a question with both "c" and "c++".  Here the answer definitely depends on which language you're using.  (See also C++03 Standard C.1.6[on 8.5.2].)

Comment: @aschepler why oh why did c++ ever become something other than "c with classes"

Comment: why not use char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need for a compiler option, it's *already* non-NUL terminated.  The standard says a NUL should only be added if it can fit, otherwise it would be an overflow. It may just be that the next byte in memory past your array is `\0`

> **§ 6.7.8p14**
>   An array of character
>   type may be initialized by a character
>   string literal, optionally
>        enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string
>   literal (***including the
>        terminating null character if there is room*** or if the array is of
>   unknown size) initialize the
>        elements of the array.

Comment: +1, your answer is better than mine because it quotes the standard. :-)

Comment: It should be noted that this is different in C++ than it is in C. C++ requires that a char array initializer using a string literal must append the '\0' - the good(?) news is that it'll generate a compile time error if you try to compile code that depends on this behavior as C++.

Comment: @GlassGhost - if you need something that works in both C and C++ you'll need to use wallyk's solution.

Comment: @GlassGhost - if you're asking whether marking the array as `extern "C"` in a C++ compile might help, I'm afraid it won't.

Comment: I do have a question. I have written a program in which I initialize the char array to a string(char by char and giving size in between square brackets), and then I print it. But this does not result into a error because the array is  not null terminated. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 9):

No.  NUL-terminated strings are intrinsic to the language.  You can have a character array though, and set each character one by one:

```
char hex [] = {'0', '1', '2', ... 'F'};
```

Comment: Good answer.  Just a note that it appears that the OP is interested in declaring an array of exactly 16 bytes so it might be helpful to include the array size specifier in your example...`const char hex[16] = {'0', '1', '2', ... 'F'};`

Comment: They may be intrinsic but the compiler, by way of the standard, cannot NUL terminate a string if it doesn't fit.  There is no need to parse it out character-by-character as you have written because it's *already* non-NUL terminated the way the OP has it.

Comment: @SiegeX: at the time I posted my answer, the question did not have a C++ tag.

Comment: likewise.  The standard I was referring to is the 'C99' standard but it should also apply to ANSI C as well.

Answer (score 5):

You answered your own question. If you explicitly give the array a length, as in:

```
const char hex[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

then of course it won't be null-terminated because there is no storage reserved for null termination. (`hex[16]` is outside the bounds of the object and thus reading or writing it is undefined behavior. If it happens to read as 0, that's UB for ya...)

It's only if you leave the length implicit, as in:

```
const char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

or if you use the string literal as an object rather than as an initializer, that it will have null termination.

By the way, why do you care if the null termination is there or not, if you're not planning to use it. Are you trying to shave bytes off your binary? :-)

Comment: @R.: The fact that null termination might be an issue is an abstraction leak in the C, and as such unavoidable. In other languages one could simply define a type allowing only values 0..15, and using this type as the array index. This would prevent overflows of the defined array.

Comment: And it would make everyone's life type-hell. The more types a language  (or even a library) has, the harder it is to use correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question is a bit unclear: In C, the qoted initialization:

```
static const char hex[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

is legal. In C++, it is not. So it is one of the pieces of code, that fail (fortunately at compile time), when you move from C to C++.

It would be nice to have a way to force string literals without termination \0 byte. Something like:

```
static const char hex[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF\!0";
```

where the `\!0` at the end tells the compiler to not zero-terminate the string! `\!` or even `\!0` anywhere else in the string would behave unmodified, so just put out a literal `!` or `!0` .

Comment: The double quotes makes the compiler treat your input as a zero-terminated string. If you want 16 random characters (which may or may not include a literal 0), simply don't use double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a partly solution for this issue in C++17: `constexpr` functions may return objects of type `std::array`. So, instead of initializing a const C array, we initialize a constexpr C++ `std::array` instead. This template function strips the terminator:

```
template<typename CHAR, unsigned long N>
constexpr inline std::array<CHAR, N-1> strip_terminator(const CHAR (&in)[N])
{
    std::array<CHAR, N-1> out {};
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
        out[i] = in[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

And it can be used as follows:

```
constexpr std::array<char, 16> hex = strip_terminator("0123456789ABCDEF");
```

Everything is done at compile time, even with optimization off: The array `hex` becomes a constant of the desired size and the desired content, without the unwanted zero termination byte.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are null terminated in C. If you want to populate a non-null-terminated char array you can use an array initializer.